# How to get array key by value from array in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

How to get array key by value from array in smarty template?

From below i can get last inserted key but i need particular key from value in smarty.

```
{$array|@array_keys|@array_pop}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following array:

```
$smarty->assign("array", [
    '0' => 5,
    'a' => 'abc',
    'd' => 'xyz'
]);
```

you can now use in Smarty:

```
{assign var="key" value='xyz'|array_search:$array}

{if $key !== false}
    The key is {$key}
{/if}
```

to find key for given value in array. Of course it will work as described for [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function

Comment: I got an error: Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/public_html/templates_c/^4eeee20cc3daff86621c7111151842bdb0f27b10.file.page.tpl.php on line 55

Comment: @SouravBasak Have you assigned this array in PHP as I showed? If yes, show your `$array` and value you are looking in the array.

Comment: yes i assigned and it throws error as i mentioned above. @Marcin Nabiałek